# Laravel eloquent join with min() and get first result of relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables named `products` and `merchants`.
`products` table schema:

| id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | product |
| 2 | Product 2 | product-2 |

`merchants` table schema:

| id | store | price | mrp | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amazon | 99 | 120 | 1 |
| 2 | Amazon | 149 | 179 | 2 |
| 3 | Ebay | 80 | 120 | 1 |

Each product can have multiple merchants and are related using `hasMany` relationship.
Now I want to fetch both products to show on homepage **BUT** I only need is one merchant **HAVING** the lowest price.
I tried using `join` where price is min()

```
Product::leftJoin('merchants', function ($q) {
         $q->on('products.id', '=', 'merchants.product_id')
           ->where('merchants.price', '=', DB::raw("(select min(`price`) from merchants)"));
})->get();
```

and the output is:

```
[{
    "id": 3, //ID gets replaced by merchant id
    "name": "Product",
    "slug": "product",
    "store": "Ebay",
    "price": 80,
    "mrp": 120
}, {
    "id": null, //ID is null
    "name": "Product 2",
    "slug": "product-2",
    "store": null, //Should be Amazon
    "price": null, //Should be 149
    "mrp": null //Should be 179
}]
```

It shows first product properly, only joining merchant with minimum price but values of other products is coming null.
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have eloquent models defined properly. You could try the below.

Add an extra relation function to your product model.

```
public function cheapMerchant() {
    return $this->hasOne(Merchant::class, 'product_id')->orderBy('price', 'asc');
}
```

Then in your controller, access the data by executing.

```
Product::with('cheapMerchant')->get();
```

This will give you a `cheapMerchant` relation object.

Comment: I actually tried this but I also want to be able to sort the products by their price.

Comment: @SukhchainSingh Great to hear that. Keep doing your best and help others.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the lowest price of all merchants. Instead, you want the lowest price possible for your product.

```
Product::leftJoin('merchants', function ($q) {
         $q->on('products.id', '=', 'merchants.product_id')
           ->havingRaw('merchants.price = ?', [ DB::raw("min(`merchants.price`)") ]);
})->get();
```

or:

```
Product::leftJoin('merchants', function ($q) {
         $q->on('products.id', '=', 'merchants.product_id')
           ->where('merchants.price', '<', '`price')
           ->orderByDesc('merchants.price')
           ->limit(1);
})->get();
```

Comment: First query outputs empty result.
Second query outputs null results on relationship fields. But removing `where('merchants.price', '<', 'price')` outputs 3 merchants instead of 2.

Comment: Can you please explain what does `= ?` this mean?

Comment: `= ?` means that `?` is a placeholder whose value is passed as the second parameter

Comment: What is the raw SQL from the first query?

Comment: Thank you, I did it with hasOne relationship then sorting collection using sortBy.